# Halides in s-block elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, periodic-table

What is the reason behind the following statement:

> The $Δ_fH^\circ$ for the fluorides become less negative as we go down the group while the reverse is true for chlorides, bromides and iodides.